# filling a 2d array random

Tags: c++, c

this code will good for n<20, but for n=40 give me access violation error:
this code will fill X and O  random.

```
 int i=0,j=0;
 int x=0,y=0;
 int n=40;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     for(j=0;j<n;j++)
         arr[i][j]='O';
 }

 srand(clock());
 for(i=0;i<n*n;i++)
 {
   x = rand()%n;
   y = rand()%n;
   if(arr[x][y] == 'O') arr[x][y]='X';
 }
```

Declare:

```
 arr = (char**)malloc(n);
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    arr[i] = (char*)malloc(n);
```

Comment: Why not just randomly set the value to `X` or `O` in the first loop?

Comment: Can we see your `arr` declaration too?

Comment: Man I hate 2D array malloc.  I never get it right.  My guess is that there's nothing that forces malloc above to keep memory contiguous so it will randomly fail.

Comment: you can use memory from stack if the array will be small, it's a lot easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
arr = (char**)malloc(n);
```

to

```
arr = (char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
```

Answer (score 4):

you could do :-

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         for(j=0;j<n;j++)
             arr[i][j]= ((rand() % 2) == 0) ? 'O' : 'X';
     }
```

and make sure your array is n by n.  Instead of those multiple mallocs, which will allocate memory from all over the place...

```
 arr = (char**)malloc( n * n * sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<n*n;i++)
{
   x = rand()%n;
   y = rand()%n;
   if(arr[x][y] == 'O') arr[x][y]='X';
   ...
```

`n*n`? `arr` only has `n` elements and `arr[0...n-1]` each only have `n` elements. If `x` or `y` is `>= n`, you'll be accessing elements past the end of your array and causing undefined behaviour. In this case your lucky because it causes an access violation.

That, and `arr = (char**)malloc(n);` should be `arr = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));`.

Answer (score 0):

If n is constant, or your compiler supports C99, you can initalize it as a 1-d, then cast it to a pointer-to array:

```
int i;
char (*arr)[n] = malloc(n*n);
char *vals = (char*)arr;

for(i=0; i<n*n; i++)
   vals[i] = (rand()%2)?'X':'O';

//now, use arr[y][x] as usual
```